# CMake: USES_TERMINAL argument in add_custom_command(TARGET) does not use console pool with Ninja

Tags: cmake, ninja

In CMake, if I use `add_custom_command` with `USES_TERMINAL` in order to get a prompt for a user's password when running a command using `sudo`, as seen in the following CMakeLists.txt snippet:

```
add_executable(my-app main.c)

add_custom_command(
    TARGET my-app
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip $<TARGET_FILE:my-app>
    USES_TERMINAL
)
```

And then configure and build using Ninja:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -B build
$ cmake --build build
```

The prompt for the user's password does not appear, and the build hangs.  Looking at the resulting `build.ninja` file, I would expect there to be a `pool = console` setting for building my-app, but it's not present:

```
build my-app: C_EXECUTABLE_LINKER__my-app_ CMakeFiles/my-app.dir/main.c.o
  OBJECT_DIR = CMakeFiles/my-app.dir
  POST_BUILD = cd /home/bob/test_cmake_uses_terminal/build && sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip /home/bob/test_cmake_uses_terminal/build/my-app
  PRE_LINK = :
  TARGET_COMPILE_PDB = CMakeFiles/my-app.dir/
  TARGET_FILE = my-app
  TARGET_PDB = my-app.pdb
```

If I manually add `pool = console` to that list, it properly prompts for the user's password when runnning the command.

I was able to get this to work in a more kludgey way using `add_custom_target`, but I'd like to know why `USES_TERMINAL` is not working as I interpret the documentation.

I'm using cmake version 3.24.1 and running on Ubuntu 22.04, if that helps.

---

Update:

Bug report submitted regarding this issue:  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25040

Comment: Have you considered [raising a bug report](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues) I tried searching for one that sounds like your problem and didn't find one. If you do raise one, please [edit] a link to it into your question post here.

Comment: @starball My first instinct is always that I'm doing something wrong, so I came here first.  I'll submit a bug if it appears that something is actually wrong with cmake.

Comment: Note, that description "With the Ninja generator, this places the command in the console pool." corresponds to "Generating Files" flavor of `add_custom_command` (with `OUTPUT` keyword). In the form of "Build Events" (with `TARGET` keyword) the option USES_TERMINAL is applicable too, but CMake [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events) doesn't describe it. I guess that pool is no longer assigned in that flavour, because the command becomes **part of the other command**. Note, that signature in that case misses `JOB_POOL` parameter.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Yes, I was confused by the fact that USES_TERMINAL was not documented for the "Build Events" flavor of `add_custom_command`, but just assumed that it behaved identically to the "Generating FIles" flavor.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that `USES_TERMINAL` was never intended to be used when calling `add_custom_command` with `TARGET` in its signature.

The best way to have the terminal available to the custom command is to set the property `JOB_POOL_LINK` to `console` on the target on which the custom command is being added:

```
set_property(TARGET my-app PROPERTY JOB_POOL_LINK console)
add_custom_command(
    TARGET my-app
    POST_BUILD
    COMMAND sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip $<TARGET_FILE:my-app>)
```

One other potential workaround would be to use `add_custom_target` with the `USES_TERMINAL` parameter, but this results in undesirable behavior of the command being executed on every build:

```
add_custom_target(
    run_sudo_setcap
    ALL
    COMMAND sudo setcap cap_net_admin+eip $<TARGET_FILE:my-app>
    DEPENDS my-app
    USES_TERMINAL)
```

---

Solution taken from the recommendation posted on the bug report related to this issue:  https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/25040#note_1381770

And note that the newest docs for CMake will no longer show `USES_TERMINAL` as a supported parameter to the `add_custom_command(TARGET)` command:

https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/merge_requests/8602

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events